# RewriteRule .htaccess multiple params

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite my url, but I'm getting an error "500 Internal Server Error"

I've never done this before, and I've read some tutorials but I can't say I got any smarter from it.

The .htaccess file is in the root directory (/var/www)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /sub_domain/directory_to_my_files/
RewriteRule ^([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)/(.*)/$ /index.php?pos=$1:$2&text=$3
```

The current link goes like this:
http://sub_domain.my_domain.com/directory_to_my_files/index.php?pos=(float|integer-only):(float|integer-only)&text=(any-text)

But I'm trying to do this:
http://sub_domain.my_domain.com/directory_to_my_files/(float|integer-only):(float|integer-only)/(any-text)/

Sorry if the links is a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be placed in **`/directory_to_my_files/.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory_to_my_files/

RewriteRule ^(-?[0-9.]+)[:-]([0-9.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pos=$1:$2&text=$3 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: Ok, so I've put the .htaccess in my **/subdomain/direcotry_to_my_files** now and using the code you provided.

But it's telling me 404 Page not Found.

Error: **File does not exist: /var/www/subdomain/directory_to_my_files/-1000.0:1000.0**

The url I try:
**http://subdomain.my-site.com/directory_to_my_files/-1000.0:1000.0/My awesome text!**

Comment: ok try updated rule now. Your URL seems different from the regex you have in your question.

Comment: Works now, but I can't use the flags you use for some reason. It fails to load my .js (404 not found) --- Using [R,L] works fine, but I don't want it to redirect me to the url with params, any suggestions?

Comment: Fact that with `R` it works proves that rule is right. However it is your code in `index.php` that probably is not using `$_GET` variables properly to work with internal rewrite.

Comment: I'm using the $_GET data to "transfer" it to an js array. (And I don't use the $_GET in my php script). It it any work-around fox for that?

Comment: Sorry question is about rewrite rule only. I will need to look into your PHP code of transferring GET array to JS but that should be placed in a new question after closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this locally: 
( I did not need the rewrite base )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)/(.*) /index.php?pos=$1:$2&text=$3 [R,L]
```

And it has redirected me 
from

http://loc.domain/555-666/misc-text

to

http://loc.domain/index.php?pos=555:666&text=misc-text

I reckon this was what you wanted?

About the [R,L] at the end:
the R is telling apache to actually redirect, not just rewrite the url - this helps with testing.
the L is saying this is the last rule

Edit: could it be that the rewriteBase is causing you problems?   Try it without and see if it works - at least you can nail where the problem is, then.

Comment: For some reason that still give me the "500" error. Anyway, I guess I need to use RewriteBase, I want to rewrite the url of other scripts in different sobdomains from same file (.htaccess) as well (if possible?)